# How to modify advlink.js?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

What I thought should have been easy has now taken great amount of my time.

I'm simply trying to edit some text in the /plugins/advlink/js/advlink.js file.

Consider this function:

```
function getTargetListHTML(elm_id, target_form_element) {
    var targets = tinyMCEPopup.getParam('theme_advanced_link_targets', '').split(';');
    var html = '';
    html += '<select id="' + elm_id + '" name="' + elm_id + '" onchange="this.form.' + target_form_element + '.value=';
    html += 'this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
    html += '<option value="_self">' + tinyMCEPopup.getLang('advlink_dlg.target_same') + '</option>';
    html += '<option value="_blank">' + tinyMCEPopup.getLang('advlink_dlg.target_blank') + ' (_blank)</option>';
    html += '<option value="_parent">' + tinyMCEPopup.getLang('advlink_dlg.target_parent') + ' (_parent)</option>';
    html += '<option value="_top">' + tinyMCEPopup.getLang('advlink_dlg.target_top') + ' (_top)</option>';

    for (var i=0; i<targets.length; i++) {
        var key, value;

        if (targets[i] == "")
        continue;

        key = targets[i].split('=')[0];
        value = targets[i].split('=')[1];

       html += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + ' (' + key + ')</option>';
    }

    html += '</select>';

    return html;
}
```

If I make changes to for example `advlink_dlg.target_blank` in the appropriate language file, the changes seems to show up ok.

But if I try to change the `' (_blank)'` on the same line to whatever, eg. `' (__blank)'`, nothing happens. 
Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried to override the function using the develement tools (firebug etc) to make sure you didn't include the wrong js file etc?

Comment: I've tried adding console.logs in every file I've edited, for nothing. I think there's only two possible files to edit for the section I'm working on, one being advlink.js and another being link.js under /themes/advanced. I can't figure out any other file I should check out.

Comment: Look inside the HTML if the correct one is being loaded. If your changes are not vuisible inside the browser, you've got something about the path wrong. Also, sometimes, some CMS have a cache mechanism, that can drive you nuts... if you don't know about it.

Comment: Cache it was. Thanks for your help twall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did should work!

I changed the line (in `/plugins/advlink/js/advlink.js`) to

```
html += '<option value="_blank">' + tinyMCEPopup.getLang('advlink_dlg.target_blank') + ' (XXXXXXXXXXXX_blank)</option>';
```

and see what i got after selecting some text + pushing the link-button:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for proving I'm not completely insane. Just to be extra careful, I copy-pasted the line you entered and placed it as a line 517 in `/plugins/advlink/js/advlink.js`. No change whatsoever. Still outputs just `(_blank)` to the browser.

Comment: Clearing the cache helped. Should have thought it right away. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: glad to have been able to help